# Why does c script only rename in last execution of loop

Tags: c, file-rename

I am using C Script within Siemens WinCC 7.0 to read a text file containing source and destination comma separated e.g.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C File Transfer Test\Source\Cat.txt,P:\Cat.txt
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C File Transfer Test\Source\Cat1.txt,P:\Cat1.txt
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C File Transfer Test\Source\Cat2.txt,P:\Cat2.txt
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C File Transfer Test\Source\Cat3.txt,P:\Cat3.txt
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C File Transfer Test\Source\Cat4.txt,P:\Cat4.txt
```

I am using the following code to open this file and loop through moving the files from source to destination

```
#include "apdefap.h"


void File_Transfer()
{
    #define MODUL   "CopyProjekt "
    char pathIn[100];
    char pathOut[100];
    char szProjektname[255];
    FILE * fpInFile ;
    FILE * fpOutFile ;
    FILE *TempSource;
    FILE *TempDestination;  
    #pragma code ("kernel32.dll")
    BOOL CopyFileA(LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,BOOL);
    #pragma code ()
    DM_DIRECTORY_INFO dmDirInfo;
    DM_PROJECT_INFO dmProjectInfo;
    CMN_ERROR dmError;
    char *source;
    char *destination; 
    char line[1000];
    char * tokens;
    char *tempTokens;
    int i;
    char tempString[1000];
    if (DMGetProjectDirectory("PDLRT", szProjektname, &dmDirInfo, &dmError )!= NULL)
    {   
        strcat(pathIn , dmDirInfo.szProjectDir) ;
        strcat(pathOut, dmDirInfo.szProjectDir) ;
        strcat(pathIn ,"FilesForTransfer\\FileData.txt");
        strcat(pathOut ,"FilesForTransfer\\FileDataTemp.txt");
        //(NULL,pathIn ,"2", MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);      
    }
    //Open the file containing the folder names and paths
    fpInFile = fopen(pathIn,"r" );
    fpOutFile = fopen(pathOut,"w" );
        while (fgets(line,sizeof line,fpInFile) != NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,line,"Read Line",MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            tempTokens = line;
            tokens = strtok(tempTokens ,",");
            while (tokens != NULL)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    source = tokens ;   
                }
                else 
                {
                    destination = tokens ;
                }
                i = i + 1;              
                //read the tokens again
                tokens = strtok(NULL ,",");
            }           
    //MessageBox(NULL,source ,destination, MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            //Move the file from source to destination
            //if (CopyFileA(source,destination,FALSE) != 0)             
            if (rename(source ,destination )!=0)
            {
    MessageBox(NULL,"FAILED" ,"Transfer", MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            }
            else
            {
         MessageBox(NULL,"PASSED","Transfer",MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            }
        }       
    //rename(source,destination)
    //fputs(tempstring,fpOutFile );

    fclose(fpInFile );
    fclose(fpOutFile );
    remove(pathIn);
    rename(pathOut ,pathIn );

    //MessageBox(NULL,"done"  ,"Done" , MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
}
```

The message boxes are executing properly every time and the source and destination will be displayed correctly. However only the last file rename will work. If there is only one line in the reference file of source,destination then it will work fine. If there are more than one it will only work on the last.

From what I can work out the code is running through the loop properly and getting the right data from the lookup file but the rename is just not working properly.
Any ideas would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) stores the new-line character in the buffer it is populating if found:

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in str. The produced character string is always NULL-terminated. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or **a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.**

So the `destination` file name will contain the new-line character, which is illegal. Remove it before attempting the `rename()`:

```
char* nl_ptr = strrchr(destination, '\n');
if (nl_ptr) *nl_ptr = 0;
```

The last line works because there is no new-line character.

Comment: sorry for being stupid, but how do you remove the new line character?

Comment: @user2291370, refresh your page.